# Tensorflow Serving - grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with: status = StatusCode. UNAVAILABLE

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I got the following issue when trying to serve TF models using TF serving server

```
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "Connect Failed"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1583228501.130612312","description":"Failed to create subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":2267,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1583228501.130568965","description":"Pick Cancelled","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":242,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1583228501.130161019","description":"Connect Failed","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/subchannel.cc","file_line":962,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1583228501.130118961","description":"Failed to connect to remote host: Connection refused","errno":111,"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_client_posix.cc","file_line":207,"os_error":"Connection refused","syscall":"connect","target_address":"ipv4:127.0.0.1:8500"}]}]}]}"
```

I'm using docker as below

FROM tensorflow/serving:1.14.0

```
tensorflow_model_server 
   --port=${SERVING_PORT:-8500} 
   --rest_api_port=8501 
   --model_config_file=/tf_models.config 
   --tensorflow_intra_op_parallelism=1
   --tensorflow_inter_op_parallelism=1
```

Basically, the serving model server is working pretty good. But sometime it raises the error above (maybe because there are a lot of requests to the serving server). Do I need to increase the `parallelism` params or is there any way to tune the server to support more requests?

Answer (score 0):

It definitely seems to be indicating that no communication could be established between the TensorFlow server and the client.

My suspicion is that the notation for specifying a default environment variable value (`${SERVING_PORT:-8500}`) is not supported for whatever reason.

One way to test this is simply to hard-code the port and confirm whether or not this change resolves the issue.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but the weird thing is that the issue does not happen all the time, serving server is still working well. Do you think it may get lot of requests and it's auto restarted, during the time it's restarted, client cannot connect to?

Comment: That is strange... I don't think it should restart unless new models become available... Are new models being made available?